# Adding a MeshFilter mesh via script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

How do you add a MeshFilter component with a specific mesh, let's say a Capsule mesh (from Unity default library resources), via C#? I'm this far ...

```
GameObject obj = new GameObject("Player");
MeshFilter meshFilter = obj.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
meshFilter.mesh =
```

Capsule and other primitive meshes are in the Unity default resources and I know how to assign it in the editor but how do I obtain one in C#? Obviously instantiaion isn't available since it's a library asset.

**UPDATE**:

I would have thought that this would work:

```
meshFilter.mesh = Resources.Load<Mesh>("Capsule");
```

But the mesh is still null afterwards in the editor component inspector.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Since you so dutifully removed it why not also try to answer my question? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not aware about a direct way how to would not know a direct way how to do it, but there is the "hacky" way:

```
MeshFilter meshfilter = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
GameObject go = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Capsule);
meshfilter.mesh = go.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
meshfilter.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
Destroy(go);
```

Does that help?

Comment: Yes that helps, thanks! I figured out a very similar approach: Creating a `GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Capsule)` and simply use that as the base for my game object creation. I only need to remove the Mesh Renderer from it since I don't need that.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
GameObject obj=GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Capsule);
obj.name="Player";
```

Comment: Nope, that creates a `GameObject` but not a `Mesh`. I already tried that.

Comment: You can get the mesh with `obj.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh` no?

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. I don't need to get the mesh, I need to set it to a Capsule Mesh from the Unity default resources.